# color space transformation in opencv (RGB -> LAB) - red does not produce expected values

Tags: python, opencv

The following creates a red image using the RGB color 255,0,0

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

width = 5
height = 2

array = np.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
array[:,:] = [255, 0, 0] # make it red

print(array)

plt.imshow(array)
plt.show()
```

Outputs:

```
[[[255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]

 [[255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]]
```

[image]

If I transform the array into the LAB space:

```
array = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)

print(array)
```

The results look like this:

```
[[[ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]]

 [[ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]
  [ 82 207  20]]]
```

According to http://colorizer.org/ the value of red should be:

```
lab(53.23, 80.11, 67.22)
```

Why is opencv producing different values? Am I missing something? Is there a site where I can lookup, for example, red in Lab color numbers for opebcv? Thanks.

PS:

One issue is that I used COLOR_BGR2LAB instead of COLOR_RGB2LAB (thanks Mark Setchell) but it still does not result in the expected vector of 53.23, 80.11, 67.22 it produces: 54.4 83.2 78. which is not close but not the same ...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

width = 5
height = 2

array = np.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
array[:,:] = [255, 0, 0] # make it red

print(array)

array = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
array = array / 2.5

print(array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the image in RGB order, so this

```
array = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
```

should be:

```
array = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
```

If you display it using **OpenCV** `cv2.imshow(array)` and `cv2.waitKey()` you will see **OpenCV** considers it blue.

---

As regards the discrepancy you see between the online converter and **OpenCV**, I can only assume this has something to do with rounding errors arising from using `uint8` for the RGB values. If you convert to `float` type, the issue goes away:

```
Lab = cv2.cvtColor(array.astype(np.float32), cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)

# Result
array([[[53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125]],

       [[53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125],
        [53.240967, 80.09375 , 67.203125]]], dtype=float32)
```

---

As an aside, I note that `scikit-image` chooses to automatically return you a `float` when you pass it `uint8`:

```
from skimage import color
import numpy as np

# Make a rather small red image
array = np.full((1, 1, 3), [255,0,0], dtype=np.uint8)

# Convert to Lab with scikit-image
Lab = color.rgb2lab(array)

# Result
array([[[53.24058794, 80.09230823, 67.20275104]]])
```

---

Just for fun, while we are at it, check what **ImageMagick** makes it:

```
magick xc:red -colorspace lab txt:
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,cielab
0,0: (34891.4,53351.7,17270.9)  #884BD068C376 cielab(53.2408,80.0943,67.202)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I get: 136 208 195 again not close to what I expect namely: 53.23, 80.11, 67.22 (according to http://colorizer.org/ )

Comment: They are scaled to the range 0..255 (to fit an 8-bit unsigned byte) rather than 0..100. Divide by 2.55

Comment: Ok thanks Guess 54.4 83.2 78. i sclose enough to 53.23, 80.11, 67.22 ?

Comment: I'm not at a computer, but you could try using `float` to see if you get closer `array = cv2.cvtColor(array.astype(np.float32),  cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)`

Comment: well thanks for clarifying you are not a computer. I added a PS: in my question with reproducible code ...

Comment: I'm not **AT** a computer

Comment: Haha sorry Mark. When you are at a computer, could you please run the reproducible code? I cannot accept as it stands IMHO.

Comment: Now that I am at a computer ;-) I have updated my answer, please have another look.

Comment: Cool - sorry it took so long - glad we got there in the end 

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to divide by 255. This way you have the same results as SKimage and Matlab...

```
cv2.cvtColor(array.astype('float32')/255., cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)
```

otherwise it gives wrong ranges.
you can change the value of the array and check:

```
width = 5
height = 1

array = np.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
array[:,:] = [150, 20, 255] # make it red

print(array)

array2=rgb2lab(array )
print(array2.max(), array2.min())

array3 = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)
print(array3 .max(), array3 .min())

array4 = cv2.cvtColor(array.astype('float32'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)

print(array4 .max(), array4 .min())

array5 = cv2.cvtColor(array.astype('float32')/255., cv2.COLOR_RGB2Lab)

print(array5 .max(), array5 .min())
```